# How to get the last entered input from text widget in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

## This is only a sample code.

```
input = text_widget.get("1.0","end-1c")
```

I have understood that "1.0" means to get the input from the very first character in Text Widget and "end-1c" is to get retrieve till the last line excluding the newline character.

But how can I get the last entered line in the text widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always guaranteed to be a newline at the end, so the last line of text excluding this newline ends with `"end-1c"` as you suggest. The text widget supports adding one of a small set of modifiers to an index. These modifiers are "linestart",  "lineend", "wordstart" and "wordend".

Thus, to get the beginning of the last line we can append the modifier "linestart" to that index.

Example:

```
input = text_widget.get("end-1c linestart", "end-1c")
```

Comment: The given answer works. But why do we need do use "end-1c linestart", instead of  "end linestart"? Because we only need to get to the starting point  of the end line.  What is the reason for "-1c"

Comment: @learner: because "end" represents the point just after the trailing newline. "linestart" effectively means to go backwards until you find a newline. Since "end" is _after_ the last newline, backing up to the newline means it stops at that trailing newline.